# Python incorrectly referencing column in csv

Tags: python, csv

Python: version 3.6

Editor: Notepad++

Link to files: [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RanaDataViz/python_reference_csv)

---

Trying to reference individual columns in [list.csv](https://github.com/RanaDataViz/python_reference_csv/blob/master/list.csv)

I can reference the entire column, but when I use subscripts, it only references a single character.

Below is the code ([link on GitHub](https://github.com/RanaDataViz/python_reference_csv/blob/master/process_string.py))

```
import csv
import re

with open("search_file.csv") as source, open("list.csv") as module_names, open("Final_File.csv","w",newline="") as result:
    reader=csv.reader(source)
    module=csv.reader(module_names)
    writer=csv.writer(result)
    for s in module_names:
        print(s)
        k=s[1]
        l=s[2]
        print(k)
        print(l)
```

Here is the output

```
choco,Chocolate

h
o
shake,Milkshake

h
a
lime,Lemon Meringue

i
m
```

However, this is the output I am looking for. Where am I going wrong?

```
choco,Chocolate

choco
Chocolate

shake,Milkshake

shake
Milkshake

lime,Lemon Meringue

lime
Lemon Meringue
```

Comment: `for s in module:` not `for s in module_names:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to iterate over the rows of the CSV, you can iterate over the reader object (i.e. `module`).

You can then print the comma-delimited row and the first and second columns (where the column indexing starts at 0).

```
import csv
import re

with open("search_file.csv") as source, open("list.csv") as module_names, open("Final_File.csv","w") as result:
    reader=csv.reader(source)
    module=csv.reader(module_names)
    writer=csv.writer(result)
    for s in module:
        print(','.join(s))
        print ''
        k=s[0]
        l=s[1]
        print(k)
        print(l)
        print ''
```